# WPF form crashes on Windows 10 when trying to acess Outlook adress book

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I haven't been able to figure this one out by myself so I thought I'd give you a shot at it.

The program itself is comparing a list of employees to a PDL from the Outlook adress book. The issue is that my WPF form works perfectly fine on Windows 7,  however the program crashes on Windows 10 when I try to access the Outlook adress book, everything else works the way it's supposed to.

This is the code to access Outlook:

```
    public class Outlookhelper
    {

    public List<String> GetDistributionListMembers()
    {
        List <String> returnlist = new List <String>();
        Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd =
            application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
        Outlook.AddressLists addrLists =
            application.Session.AddressLists;
        foreach (Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists) 
        {
            if (addrList.Name == "Global Adress List")
            {
                snd.InitialAddressList = addrList;
                break;
            }
        }
        snd.NumberOfRecipientSelectors =
            Outlook.OlRecipientSelectors.olShowTo;
        snd.ToLabel = "D/L";
        snd.ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = true;
        snd.AllowMultipleSelection = false;
        snd.Display();
        if (snd.Recipients.Count > 0)
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
                snd.Recipients[1].AddressEntry;
            if (addrEntry.AddressEntryUserType ==
                Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry)
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList exchDL =
                    addrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
                Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries =
                    exchDL.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
                if (addrEntries != null)
                    foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember
                        in addrEntries)
                    {
                        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exchDLMember.Name);
                        returnlist.Add(exchDLMember.Name);
                    }
            }
        }
    return returnlist;
    }
}
```

And this is the error message I get from the Event Viewer on the Windows 10 machine:

```
Application: PDL Updater.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at



System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(System.RuntimeType, System.Object[], Boolean)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)
   at PDLUpdater.Outlookhelper.GetDistributionListMembers()
   at PDLUpdater.MainWindow.getPDLnames_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at Contacts.App.Main()
```

And

```
   Faulting application name: PDL Updater.exe, version: 1.2.9.0, time stamp: 0x58aae81e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.589, time stamp: 0x57cf948c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f28
Faulting process id: 0x2948
Faulting application start time: 0x01d28b7a4e508b20
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\PDL Updater\PDL Updater.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dd5f897a-24c9-4dd0-979e-4f0cbd747a94
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

*edit
This is the exception Message it throws me, hope it helps:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wkhb.png)

If you need anything else I'd be happy to provide it. Looking forward to getting this over with, so thank you already in advance!

Comment: Ok, so when you run it in debug, which line does it die  at?

Comment: Add exception handling in your click event handler and log the entire exception, including its message, call stack etc. You can do that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. You are trying to call an external application - there is always the possibility of a problem. Missing application, wrong interop version, whatever

Answer (score 0):

Try to target your platform:

> In Visual Studio → project properties → in the Build tab → platform target = X86/X64/Any CPU

Change the platform target and test your application.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the code on a secondary thread?

Please remember that Office applications use the single threaded apartment model. You should use OOM on the main thread only. If you want to use multithreading you need to consider using a low-level API - Extended MAPI. Or just any wrapper around that API (for example, such as Redemption).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I only recently started with C# and had to take over code written by someone else. 
Would that be an issue that occurs only on Windows 10? It puzzles me that I do not get a consistent error on both Systems. The code for this program was taken from two seperate programs that work fine on Windows 10. The only difference was that before it was a Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 0):

It sure sounds like it blows up when you try to create an instance of the Outlook.Application object.

Make sure both Outlook and your app are running in the same security context. Is either app running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator)?

Comment: Visual Study always asks for admin rights whenever I try to start the application. The setup file I created runs with admin rights as well.
I split the code into two sections to check if outlook is running or not. If outlook is not running then the application works fine. Only change to the code for the if outlook is running is
`oApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;`
which is exactly the line where the application fails

Comment: Only older versions of VS do that. The setup rights make no difference - what matters is the security context - it must be the same for *both* apps when your code is running.

Comment: But how could I achieve that? I'm creating a setup .exe with Inno Setup that requires admin privileges in order to install to Program Files and to check if .net Framework is installed (and install it if it is not). If I run the Inno setup with `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` the app works as intended but it can't check for .net and it can't install to Program Files.
Can you think of a solution for this? Maybe a way to change the Privileges in Inno Setup after installation if that is possible?

Comment: Wait a sec, are you creating OOM objects in an **installer**? Why would you do that?